# Rails 3 rake error You have already activated rake 0.9.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I run rake db:migrate in my console:

```
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 0.9.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2. C
onsider using bundle exec.

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

C:\Rails\myapp>bundle install
Using rake (0.9.2)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.9)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.5.0)
Using activemodel (3.0.9)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.4)
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Using tzinfo (0.3.30)
Using actionpack (3.0.9)
Using mime-types (1.16)
Using polyglot (0.3.2)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.2.19)
Using actionmailer (3.0.9)
Using arel (2.0.10)
Using activerecord (3.0.9)
Using activeresource (3.0.9)
Using addressable (2.2.6)
Using bundler (1.0.18)
Using multipart-post (1.1.4)
Using faraday (0.7.6)
Using friendly_id (4.0.0)
Using hashie (1.2.0)
Using json (1.6.1)
Using multi_json (1.0.4)
Using mysql (2.8.1)
Using oauth2 (0.5.2)
Using omniauth (1.0.2)
Using omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.0)
Using omniauth-facebook (1.2.0)
Using rdoc (3.10)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.0.9)
Using rails (3.0.9)
Using rest-client (1.6.7)
Using sequel (3.20.0)
Using simple_form (1.5.2)
Using sinatra (1.0)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.4)
Using sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
Using taps (0.3.23)
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem
is installed.

rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 0.9.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2. C
onsider using bundle exec.

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: have you tried `bundle exec rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: yes and it works but it is not a convenient solution...

Comment: OK, so your question is really "how can I avoid bundle exec".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably because you have a newer Rake version on your system. You can do as the error says: `bundle exec rake db:migrate` which runs rake in your application context (rake 0.9.2), or just delete your Gemfile.lock and bundle again.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, `bundle exec` of course worked in the Terminal, but RubyMine would not listen. It turned out that the `global` gemset used the newer `rake`-version than the my 'local' gem set, I ended up uninstalling `rake` from the `global` gemset to make RubyMine happy again (after a restart that is).